# O365 SharePoint CEWP with Javascript Not Loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, office365

I'm trying to execute an example using the "Etherson method" to create a web part with JavaScript. I want separate .html and .js files in a custom library as shown:
[Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAhux.png)

If I keep the js inline, the code works as expected:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/mOperations/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Demo List')/items", type: "GET", headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        }).success(function (data) {
            var listItemInfo = "";

            $.each(data.d.results, function (key, value) {
                listItemInfo += "<strong>Title: </strong>" + value.Title + " <strong>Description: </strong>" + value.Description + "<br />";
            });

            $("#divHelloWorld").html(listItemInfo);
        });
    });
</script></head><body>
<div id="divHelloWorld">Hello World!</div></body></html>
```

But if I reference an external .js file, it's like the JavaScript doesn't exist (i.e. it never gets called):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" scr="https://mysite.sharepoint.com/mOperations/webparts/SimpleExample/SimpleExample.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="divHelloWorld">Hello Worlds!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I verified the path https://mysite.sharepoint.com/mOperations/webparts/SimpleExample/SimpleExample.js is correct.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you do any debugging in Google Chrome or Internet Explorer (F12) and have a look at the network tab to be sure that the file is loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the "scr" to "src" in your html.

```
<script type="text/javascript" scr="your_js_file.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="your_js_file.js"></script>
```